# LNK2019 XAudio2Create - unresolved symbol

Tags: c++, com, xaudio2

I am trying to get in touch with the DirectX SDK. I managed to install it, created a new `Win32 Console Project` and added following lines

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xaudio2.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
IXAudio2* pXAudio = 0;
IXAudio2MasteringVoice *pXAudioMasterVoice = 0;
HRESULT hr;

CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

hr = XAudio2Create(&pXAudio, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR);
if(FAILED(hr)){
    CoUninitialize();
    return hr;
}

hr = pXAudio->CreateMasteringVoice(&pXAudioMasterVoice);
if(FAILED(hr)){
    pXAudio->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return hr;
}

CoUninitialize();
std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
}
```

The documentation says, that there is no `xaudio2.lib` to link to, but it is a `COM`-object, but I get `LNK2019 - unresolved external symbol "__imp__XAudio2Create@12"`

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.xaudio2.xaudio2create%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the documentation.

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: XAudio2Create is not COM, it's a standard DLL export. You *do* need to link with Xaudio2.lib.

Comment: Please read the "Remarks" section under the link I provided. Additionally there is NO `.lib` in the SDK folder.

Comment: I don't know what they mean by that. Using COM only would necessitate a CLSID (I don't see any provided in the .h). xaudio2.lib is available in %Program Files%\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um with the Windows 8 SDK.

Comment: Gonna have a look at this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XAudio2Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.xaudio2.xaudio2create.aspx) is not COM, it's a standard DLL export, so you do need to link with Xaudio2.lib. This library is available in `%Program Files%\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um` (installed with the Windows 8 SDK).

Comment: XAudio in Windows 8.x is version 2.8, which no longer uses COM to instantiate it. XAudio 2.7 and earlier (which are for Windows 7 and earlier) DO use COM. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

super late to the party, but I got this to work by following the windows examples [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/XAudio2-Win32-Samples-024b3933) and ensuring my includes like this:

```
#include <xaudio2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"xaudio2.lib")
```